# Entity Framework June 2011 CTP

Tags: entity-framework

Can someone provide the Microsoft Entity Framework June 2011 CTP software. I am unable to find in official website. And my project have dependency on EF 2011 CTP. I tried many ways but I am not able to find any links.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I mean, if you have something with a dependency that is 12 years old and has been unsupported for many years, perhaps it is time to upgrade?

Comment: I know but my project have dependency on this EF and by mistake our system crashed and we don't have much time to migrate with latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NuGet has a version that was released a in July 2011, which should be what you need. https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/4.1.10715

But don't expect any of the visual tooling to work in a modern version of Visual Studio.